# Will there be performance issues if a list have 50 columns in a list?

Tags: office-365, column, performance, large-lists

Depending on requirements amount of columns in a list can differ.
There has been discussions on other websits regarding performance and amount of columns.

There is usually three common options:

1. Have all columns in the same list and enable indexing.
2. Try to group the columns and create lists based on the amount of groups and connect them by using reference IDs
3. Skip Sharepoint and use SQL instead to store the data.

About deciding which approach to go can be complicated.

Here is a scenario:

Let's say 50 columns needs to be stored everytime users complete a form, would option 1 be a viable choice?

It's mostly choice fields and normal text fields.

Each row with its 50 column data will later be generated to a word file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which type of columns you are using. Have a look at another related(/duplicate) question: [Sharepoint list column limit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112216/sharepoint-list-column-limit)

To consider the "way to go":

50 fill-in fields sounds like a questionnaire or an application. Therefore SharePoint's *Survey* or an *InfoPath form* might be more suitable for your case. This question is (also) quite strongly related to UX. You might find relevant questions at https://ux.stackexchange.com/ as well.