# Create HTML table report in excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

I am getting data after filtering a list. And then I am displaying the data in an HTML table. So, in this case,

I need to get almost 200 columns in HTML table so creating it dynamically is getting tough.

So is there any easy way of doing this. Like is there a way I can use an Excel template where the columns are already created so that I only have to add rows.

Comment: IMO the initial problem is your *almost 200 columns*, which extends so many recommendations (e.g. UI/UX) and [almost reaches SharePoint's limits too](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112216/sharepoint-list-column-limit). [Don't be too busy to improve](http://i.imgur.com/LUQlnew.png), and instead design a way you can keep up with your original dynamical way.

Comment: I can hide all columns when this table is displayed on page but when export to excel is dont i need all columns.
So if it not the correct way then what should be done. Do I need to see other way of doing it. Should I not include all 200 columns at once